# Scraping historical data with BeautifulSoup/Pandas - multiple pages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup, css-tables

New to web scraping using Python and having a problem with getting data in table format from the following source: https://www.uzse.uz/trade_results?mkt_id=ALL&date=26.01.2019&search_key=

I was able to get the "raw" table from a single page:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("https://www.uzse.uz/trade_results?mkt_id=ALL&date=25.01.2019&search_key=")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
tbl = soup.find_all(class_= "col-xs-12 table-responsive")
tbl
```

However, the idea is to get all trades for a given date (multiple pages) over the past 2 years in a table format for further exploratory analysis. I am not interested in URLs in the second and third column at this point and want to keep just the name (i.e. UZ7004510002 KUMZ,  AJ).

I'd appreciate any help as I am struggling with making a progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as converting your output into a table, you certainly can use BeautifulSoup to do that, and that's ok, but does take a little work. But if I see there are `<table>` tags, my default is to go with pandas, as it'll do the work for you. And if it gives back reseaonably what I want, I go with that and just manipulate the dataframe a little if I need to:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

page = requests.get("https://www.uzse.uz/trade_results?mkt_id=ALL&date=25.01.2019&search_key=")
tables = pd.read_html(page.text)
table = tables[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (table)
             Время       ...            Объём торгов
0   25 янв., 15:02       ...            UZS  421 080
1   25 янв., 15:02       ...            UZS  261 360
2   25 янв., 15:02       ...            UZS  682 440
3   25 янв., 15:02       ...                 UZS  27
4   25 янв., 15:02       ...         UZS  15 152 000
5   25 янв., 15:02       ...         UZS  13 500 000
6   25 янв., 15:02       ...          UZS  2 008 245
7   25 янв., 15:02       ...             UZS  17 463
8   25 янв., 15:02       ...            UZS  582 100
9   25 янв., 15:02       ...             UZS  11 642
10  25 янв., 15:02       ...          UZS  6 117 871
11  25 янв., 15:02       ...            UZS  4 581,9
12  25 янв., 15:02       ...            UZS  550 000
13  25 янв., 15:02       ...          UZS  7 232 500
14  25 янв., 15:02       ...                  UZS  1
15  25 янв., 14:29       ...             UZS  32 000
16  25 янв., 14:29       ...              UZS  9 000
17  25 янв., 14:29       ...          UZS  5 337 000
18  25 янв., 14:29       ...          UZS  1 098 000
19  25 янв., 14:26       ...              UZS  122,4

[20 rows x 9 columns]
```

And like Omer says, just iterate over those values to go to the different pages.

Comment: Your version with `pandas` is more logical and easier. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This site has only one table so we can use `table` also and parse the first url's table information

```
page = requests.get("https://www.uzse.uz/trade_results?mkt_id=ALL&date=25.01.2019&search_key=")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
tbl = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'table centered-table'}).findAll('td')


array = []
for x in range(0,len(tbl)):
    array.append(tbl[x].text.strip())

print array
```

This is only just this url.You want to parse over the past 2 years so Its so long-time.

If you want to change page from bottom side . You need to change url according the number of `li` from bottom side.

You can use `Python Selenium Web Driver` for creating a robot that will automatically change the date , click button  and parse the data then return result.

Comment: thank you for looking at this. I was thinking of looping over URL (the part which says `25.01.2019`) for changing the dates. But first I need to figure out to get all the data for one single date from multiple pages ... I am also having a trouble with converting the output to a data table format ...

Comment: given url and `https://www.uzse.uz/trade_results?date=25.01.2019&mkt_id=ALL&page=1&search_key=`  is the same.You can increase one by one  `page=1 ` according to number of pages.

Comment: Yes, but I would not know the exact number of pages for each date. This should also be considered, I guess ...

Comment: Every page has `<li class="last next">` and it has a href like `/trade_results?date=25.01.2019&amp;mkt_id=ALL&amp;page=12&amp;search_key=` this `page=12` 12 is the last page in url can change each pages.You need to get this value and increase url's page according to this number